# WIX: Only check or get IIS settings when web features are being selected for installation

Tags: wix, wix3

I am using WIX here. 3.0 to be specific. I have created an installer in which I have about 6 features. 2 of which are websites for IIS. the problem is that, when I deselect the 2 web features, the installer still looks for IIS. How can I avoid that? Especially when I want to install the 4 features on a machine that does not have IIS installed? Below is a sample WebSite section I have.

```
<iis:WebSite Id="defaultWebsite" Description="Default Website">
   <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" IP="*" Port="80" />
</iis:WebSite>
```

Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029980/wix-how-not-to-call-actionstartnamestartmetabasetransaction-during-installati/4030611#4030611).